# How to test a SOAP WebService CLIENT with Arquillian

Tags: wsdl, java-ee-6, soap-client, jboss-arquillian

I try to ensure with a TestNG test, that the generation of a Java SOAP WS Client (not interested in the server stub) works properly and does not result in a null pointer exception. I do NOT even want to fire a service request - just need to test the invocation of the object.

```
@Test(enabled=true)
  public void getServiceClientTest() {
      WebServiceClient annotation = MyWS.class.getAnnotation(WebServiceClient.class);
      QName qname = new QName(annotation.targetNamespace(), annotation.name());
      URL wsdlURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(annotation.wsdlLocation());
      MyWS svc = new MyWS(wsdlURL, qname);

      // Ensure the client stub is created successfully.
      org.testng.Assert.assertNotNull(svc);
  }
```

In a Unit Test, this will result in an exception, because the files for the client generation are not in reach for the test. --> see below /myWebService

This pseudo-integrative test should be doable with Arquillian, right?

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: file:/myWebService. It failed with: 
    /myWebService (No such file or directory).
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:162)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:144)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:265)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:228)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:176)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:104)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77)
    at myWS.services.v2.MyWS.<init>(AlertTaskServiceV2.java:42)
    at WebserviceTest.getServiceClientTest(VerificationTaskImplTest.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /myWebService (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.createReader(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:804)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.resolveWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:262)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:129)
    ... 9 more
```

How do you do that in a Arquillian Test?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Arquillian client mode](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/Test+run+modes) in which case ARQ will deploy/undeploy your server part and run the client part on your local JVM.

Answer (score 1):

Just as Franck suggested you could use the client mode, which be nearly the same as running a regular TestNG test. You can do that at the test level with the `@RunAsClient` annotation.

If you need it to be deployed you'd also need to include any generated classes into your deployment, which may or may not be happening yet as you didn't include that part of the test class